# Intellij IDE, JSDK home directory

Tags: intellij-idea

I use linux. What's all about JSDK home directory?
What directory should i set?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Linux distribution and JDK installation location. In any case you can download Sun (Oracle?) JDK and install it manually (using either .bin or .rpm distribution). Then configure the chosen installation location in IDEA.

Comment: I had it installed via package manager (pacman), now i downloaded JDK.bin and installed manually, finally works

Comment: pacman means that you are most likely on Arch Linux, then the default JDK location on your system would be either /opt/java or a directory under /usr/lib/jvm.

Comment: IDEA is looking for standard JDK layout, most likely your distribution is packaging it in some weird way.